# Is there a way to avoid the re-calculation of the same centroid without creating a new column?

Tags: postgis, sql

All tables contain polygon geometries.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1, table2, table3, table4
WHERE
    st_contains(table2.geom, st_centroid(table1.geom)) AND
    st_contains(table3.geom, st_centroid(table1.geom)) AND
    st_contains(table4.geom, st_centroid(table1.geom)) AND
```

Will the centroid be calculated more than once or is postgis/postgresql able to resolve it. If not, is there a possibility to improve the performance without creating a centroid column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a common table expression, CTE, to first calculate the values of the centroids, eg,

```
WITH 
    centroids(geom) AS 
      (SELECT ST_Centroid(geom) 
         FROM table1)
SELECT t2.*, t3.*, t4.* 
  FROM table2 t2, table3 t3, table3 t4, centroids ct
WHERE ST_Contains(t2.geom, ct.geom)
  AND ST_Contains(t3.geom, ct.geom)
.....
```

In the case of your query, where ST_Centroid(table1.geom) is reused multiple times, it is highly likely that the Postgres query optimizer will rewrite the query so that ST_Centroid(table1.geom) is only called once. You can verify this by putting [`EXPLAIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-explain.html) in front of your query and comparing the two plans. Explain plans can be quite difficult to comprehend at first, but I suspect the output will be the same for this query written both ways, meaning that while in SQL/English you are concerned about repeating yourself, the parsed query will not do so.

In general, if you need to refer to some input table multiple times in a complex query, but using a different subset of the data, different columns, or different function calls on that data, than the CTE approach is a good one, as you only have to fetch from that table once.

**NOTE**. It is quite likely that the above query will fail. I don't know what the structure of your tables is, and it is possible, if there are no shared column, you could just write `SELECT * FROM t1, t2, t3` etc. It is also possible, that if these tables share a similar structure, then you are looking for a `UNION SELECT`.

Comment: You are right my example does not work. The original example works but I made it shorter to explain my problem without writing too much code. Anyway, your answer helps a lot and is exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Actually, I meant that my answer probably wouldn't work, as I have nothing to test it against. But, I am glad the general idea helped. Use EXPLAIN whenever you can, it really helps :-)